# URL encoding a very long link and sending via email

Tags: php, email

I'm sending a link via email, the link is rather long so after some Googling, it suggests sending a rich text email with the link as an actual link - I tested this solution but have come across something else:

Here's the link:

```
www.example.com/bridge/aHR0cDovL2QxbW8zdHp4dHRhYjNuLmNsb3VkZnJvbnQubmV0L3N0YXRpYy9yZW50YWxzLzcyMC9WSU5UMDA2Ni5tcDQ%2FaWQ9MTI3NSZFeHBpcmVzPTE0MTM0NTMyMjcmU2lnbmF0dXJlPUZvWDJvU2ZjVURwbjlIMzhWN3FCR0NqMWhMUTEyZGNaaXN%2BQ2lOTGZyVDVYWkNyeXZCejBNZEtQUjZFdHU2SmsySlI3OU04dldYeE1VRVRwNVhJNlgwVERLeHQyLWhUZUdQd0JPamZqLW9%2BaTBoM0hNb29pU0ZPZmE1MFhXMXhoLWZGNFlOMVFqdTY2UlhqU1oyODVSY2tpUkFxeU1zTFJDNlptdDI0ZEhNSmlITVI4Sld5QXhEOVlVcmxOOHc1OWxkVHkzNG5ySmFPazQySk1Ca2VQYnpUSVBxZWU5MXg0dmM3QVlsby1lampldzZodVBQVWx%2BWUxIbWhRYTJEdy12RFhqNFJ2blFYWVdUdnhkRmxBMXNTREgzRzdrRjg2N25tT240ZGNvTE53SW1VUWNoNH4xSTUtQ3ZudVQwQUh6UnZSc2FnbFY2US1IRmdKUUNTbzNCUV9fJktleS1QYWlyLUlkPUFQS0FJSTVPQlNRRUdZVzNSNVVB
```

The link is built by base 64 encoding a string (to make it look pretty, I did not like the look of the URL when it's just URL encoded) and then url encoding this:

```
$url = urlencode(base64_encode($string));
```

I then send this in an rich text email, but parts of the URL are being replaced, eg.

```
DQ%2Fa
```

becomes

```
DQ/a
```

Why is this happening and is there a way around it?

I'm just sending the link by OSX Mail, but in future it cold be send via Hotmail, Gmail etc.

Comment: Are you sending it via HTML mail? Seems it might be getting converted back. `%2F` is indeed a backslash. http://www.obkb.com/dcljr/charstxt.html

Comment: don't build long urls like that. browsers have a length limit on them and will silently truncate overly-long ones. you're risking ending up with corrupted data.

Comment: @MarcB He's safe up to the point of 2000 characters. The link he posted was around 600-700 characters so I think it's fine.

Comment: I need to build long URLs, it's a policy for S3. It's just being sent via OSX mail.

Comment: What kind of data are you passing along in the url?

Comment: @Oli a canned policy for S3

Answer (score 1):

Digging up a dinosaur, but this issue is still present in 2021.

When I send long links via OSX Mail client using Rich Text, they will get decoded. Long links are very common in software like Sketch, Figma, etc.

The only solution that I was able to find is to send mail using Plain Text, but this may not work for some.

I'm on Big Sur and I never thought I'd run into such issue.
Is there any other workaroundf for this?

Comment: Does the link have to be *that* long? Can the long link be translated into a short link (256chrs URL) that when visited can be passed on to the original long link?

Comment: The links are generated automatically by the software and I have no control over it. The URL contains a hash, and a specific location of the shared design file, and that's why these URLs are usually long.

Comment: Same here with gmail url tracking in 2023. The link works just fine in Thunderbird, but when I click on it in gmail it gets urldecoded and I got garbage on my site. Not sure how to fix this.